# How would you test it? How many tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have this class (it's more pseudocode)

```
public class Roles
{
    private ProcessData processData;

    Roles(ProcessData pd)
    {
        processData = pd;
    }

    public string[] GetLoginsThatCanCallAction(string actionName)
    {
        return GetPeopleThatCanCallActionFromDb(actionName)
            .Union(processData.ProcessOwner)
            .Union(GetFromDb(Role.Administrators);
            // there may be many more Union(xyz) calls here
            .ToArray();
    }

    // I can refactor those methods to be mockable
    private GetPeopleThatCanCallActionFromDb(...)
    private GetFromDb(...)
}
```

Now my question is. Would you write one test for each Union call in GetLoginsThaatCanRunAction method?
Or is is just enough that I write one test and assert that method returns logins returned from all methods called inside GetLoginsThatCanCallAction.

I can see reasons to do it both ways. But maybe someone will convince me to on or the other solution.

Edit:
I think I wasn't clear with my question: I wanted to ask if you would write this test

```
var pd = new ProcessData()
pd.ProcessOwner = "Owner";
var r = new Roles(processData)
SetupSoThatCallsForPeopleThatCanCallActionWillReturn("Joe");
SetupSoThatCallForAdministratorsWillReturn("Administrator");

var logins = r.GetLoginsThatCanCallAction("some action");

Assert.That(logins, Contains("Owner");
Assert.That(logins, Contains("Joe");
Assert.That(logins, Contains("Administrator");
```

or would you split it into 3 separate tests with one Assert in each one?

Comment: @Uncle Iroh: If you edit question try not to change them :)

Comment: my apology if I changed your question, it read funny so I tried to make it right ;)  You also have the power to revert my changes...

Comment: Note that you cannot mock private methods such as `GetPeopleThatCanCallActionFromDb` and `GetFromDb` because it is not possible to mock private methods. You would have to make the methods protected (or public) if you want to be able to mock them.

Comment: @Arjan: I know. That's why I added comment that I can refactor them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I re-worded your question correctly, and without changing your original intent.  Are the answers not valid for your original question?

Comment: Now you're just re-wording it back to your strange wording....  I give up.  Trust me I worded it perfectly.

Comment: Your edit says:  "Should I break out my unions into separate functions that I could then unit test for one by one." Which doesn't make much sense. Union just combines results of internal methods (which are already separate). I don't want to test them one by one. They would have to be public.

Comment: @Peri one note - do not use concrete classes in unit tests other than system under test. Depend on abstraction and mock it for unit tests. Currently `Roles` and `ProcessData` classes are coupled and your test can fail due to some error in `ProcessData` class.

Comment: Highly disagree. Adding interfaces only for testing is just wrong. ProcessData is unit tested somwhere else and we are sure it works. And in this case ProcessOwner it just a simple getter setter without any logic.

Comment: @Peri If `ProcessData` is a simple DTO, then it's OK. Otherwise you will have `Roles` tests failed if error occurred in `ProcessData` class.

Comment: I guess sometimes we can't escape from this. How would you test Stack's Pop method without calling it's Push method in arrange part? If Push doesn't work then also Pop test will fail.

Comment: Unit testing frameworks such as JUnit and PHPUnit allow you to depend tests on other tests. So the `pop` test is only run when the `push` test succeeds.

Comment: @Arjan: Not sure what you mean. .NET unit testing frameworks would run both pop and push tests and show that 2 tests failed. I think JUnit works the same way. It would be misleading to see that only one test failed when in reality another 99 will also fail after I fix first one.

Comment: PHPUnit would not run the pop test if the push test fails (and you specified that the pop test depends on the push test). It will report that the push test failed and that the pop test was skipped. Imho that is the best way, because you do not know whether or not the pop test would pass if the push test were successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exercise only public API of unit under test. Your unit has single public method `GetLoginsThatCanCallAction`. It does not matter whether this method call other methods, or implemented as one large method. That's an implementation details. What really matters is whether this method correctly communicates with dependency and returns expected result:

```
// Arrange
Mock<IProcessData> processData = new Mock<IProcessData>();
processData.Setup(d => d.ProcessOwner).Returns(new[] { "Bob" });
var expected = new []{ "Bob", "Joe" };
// Act
var actual = roles.GetLoginsThatCanCallAction("Drink");
// Assert
processData.VerifyGet(d => d.ProcessOwner); // verify communication
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual); // verify result
```

Comment: Yes I know this. My question was if I should write one test for this method or as many tests as there are calls to private methods inside. In your example you are testing only that process owner is returned. So I guess you propose to write one test for each Union call? And I don't understand why there is Joe in test :) There's no setup for Joe so this test will fail.

Comment: @Peri as I pointed in answer, you should not care if there any calls to other methods. *Joe* in test for example. I don't know what requirements you have for this class. *Joe* could be returned by `GetPeopleThatCanCallActionFromDb(actionName)` call. BTW what do you mean by making methods mockable?

Comment: I meant you can't expect something if You don't set it up and it is not part of algorithm. Also I think you are contradicting yourself. You VerifyGet which is a call to other method.

Comment: @Peri no I am not. I verify call to another **object**, which is part of class responsibilities and should be verified.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. By making methods mockable I meant I can for example move them to some other class and inject instance of this class through constructor. So that I can mock this new object.

Comment: @Peri OK, I see. Regarding your question - I think you don't need three tests here, because you don't have three execution paths. Your methods is straight forward like this: take a, take b, take c and return a,b,c. If there is possible other path (e.g. `ProcessData.ProcessOwner` throws exception on some condition) then you will need test for that path. But currently simply verify that `Roles` asked its dependencies and returned all values that you provided in setup part.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting topic, Your problem is that you are trying to write a test case after you have some code developed. I would have 1 test for each Union call. The reason being do you want to test that you get a value returned from all methods OR do you want to test that under different assumptions EACH method will return a login ?

For me its more important knowing that each method will return a login based on different use cases than a generic test that will return me pass / fail.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think we test that we return people returned from those Union calls. Whoever they are. I'm not testing that these methods return correct logins as most of them will hit database.

Comment: That makes sense, I was generalizing how I would test this code. Both calls will return a person but getting that persons data is achieved via a different means. In this case it looks like a role so that would need a clear separation of testing logic. However I am sure you would have a test to check for roles as well so a single test in this instance could be acceptable. A question to ask is what are you wanting to achieve from testing this function ? What are the expectations for its execution ? This should lead to your answer on how far to test.

Answer (score 2):

I would write one test for `GetLoginsThatCanCallAction` mocking the external objects.  From your example, that would possibly mean mocking the `Union` calls.  The reason being, when I am writing this code, I am not concerned with the logic being used in `Union`.  (I have had cases where I haven't even written them yet).

If the union calls behavior can change, (IE it throws an exception), I would have a test for each of those.  However, I would have my test-suite generating those test cases for me rather than trying to write them all by hand.

You are concerned that the `GetLoginsThatCanCallAction` behaves correctly.  You also want to have control over what the `Union` calls return as well.

That being said, you would also want to have an automated test that executes the entire process that `GetLoginsThatCanCallAction` gets used in so that you are verifying the connections between the classes that you are mocking in the unit test.  Barring that not being possible actually executing the process yourself manually.

One other note, if the class is hard to test.  That is a code smell that your design is not as modular as it could be.

I would also avoid mocking internal methods of a class, if you need to do that to test the function.  It is a sign that your class has another class hiding inside.  Your class is doing more than one thing [the S in SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: I added comment that I can refactor those internal methods to be mockable. Not that I want to mock those methods.